# Yesod hamlet file error with <path> tag d attribute

Tags: haskell, yesod

```
<path class="st1" d="M72.5,38.6c0-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.2c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2c0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.1
                                                    h4.6c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.5,0.2c0.1,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.3,0.3l0.5,1l9.5,24.4c0.1,0.2,0.1,0.4-0.1,0.6c-0.1,0.2-0.4,0.2-0.7,0.2h-5.2
                                                    c-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.6-0.2c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5c-0.2-0.6-0.5-1.2-0.7-1.8c-0.2-0.6-0.5-1.2-0.7-1.8H71
                                                    c-0.2,0.6-0.5,1.2-0.7,1.8c-0.2,0.6-0.5,1.2-0.7,1.8c-0.2,0.4-0.5,0.7-0.9,0.7h-5.3c-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.6-0.2
                                                    c-0.2-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.1-0.5L72.5,38.6z M75.8,46.3c-0.2,0.6-0.5,1.3-0.7,2c-0.2,0.7-0.5,1.4-0.7,2.1c-0.2,0.7-0.5,1.4-0.7,2.1
                                                    c-0.2,0.7-0.5,1.4-0.7,2h5.5L75.8,46.3z"/>
```

In my hamlet file I have the above code. GHC complains `unexpected d,expecting ">"`

Any hint?

Comment: I think the problem is the Hamlet does not support multiple attribute values. You can put the value in your Haskell source code instead and then include via #{...}

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman thank you Michael. Could you directly include Html file?

Comment: I don't know what you mean